# In Python, how does one try (and except) the instantiation of a class?

Tags: python, oop, try-except

In Python, how does one `try`/`except` the instantiation of a class?

For example, I'm working on a GitHub script at the moment:

```
from github3 import login
user = login(username, password)
```

At first, I thought it would be as easy as:

```
try:
    user = login(username, password)
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

However if I force an exception (e.g. provide the wrong arguments), then I don't see any exceptions:

```
$ python my-script.py -u 1 -p 1; echo $?
name 'pw' is not defined
0
```

If I try again, but take the `try`/`except` out of the mix, I get the exception I expect to see:

```
$ python my-script.py -u username -p password; echo $?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delete-all-gists.py", line 19, in <module>
    user = login(u, pw)
NameError: name 'pw' is not defined
1
```

I can't be the only person who's asked this question, but I'm afraid my SO-search-fu may be failing me...

**Update**

Indeed, as mentioned in the comments, I appear to have had my eyes closed when asking this...

I think what was throwing me was that `github3`'s `login()` method was not throwing any sort of exception if the wrong username/password was provided. For example:

```
from github3 import login
u = 'foo'
p = 'bar'

try:
    user = login(u, p)
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Returns:

Nothing. No error, exception or anything.

However, the following does indeed raise an exception, as expected:

```
from github3 import login
u = 'foo'
p = 'bar'

try:
    user = login(username, p)
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Returns:

```
name 'username' is not defined
```

Which is, of course, because I purposely provided a non-existent variable as the username parameter to the `login()` method to force an exception to be raised.

Comment: you are catching all exceptions, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: The error message (`'name 'pw' is not defined'`) is bring printed, what else did you expect?!

Comment: Yeah you're catching it `print e` = `name 'pw' is not defined`.

Comment: Yes, it would appear I've made a boo boo. Thanks.

Comment: Your updated question seems to be more about GitHub's module than your title. How do you know it's not throwing an exception? What happens to `user` when you give it invalid credentials? You should be testing for that instead.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that any time you run a `try/except` block it should be because you can REASONABLY HANDLE the exception that occurs. For instance:

```
username, password = input("Username: "), input("Password: ")
while True:
    try:
        login(username, password)
    except BadPasswordException as e:
        print("Invalid login")
    else:
        # you only get here if there are no exceptions
        break
```

If you cannot reasonably handle an exception, it's best to log it and let the program gracefully exit.

```
try:
    foo(some,arguments)
except CthuluHasBeenReleasedException as e:
    logging.fatal("Oh (old) god!")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Yes your answer is correct, but it doesn't answer my question of how to specifically `try`/`catch` the *instantiation* of a class. Your answer basically tells me "If you can't handle an exception, log it and exit". I admit my question is flawed, this answer does not answer the question, IMO.

Comment: @MasterRoot24 you already know how to catch an exception thrown by instantiating a class, since you did that in your example. What you didn't know was when you should do so. I answered the question you meant to ask, because your question answered the question you asked.

Comment: My question is specifically about assigning a variable to an instance of a class (`user = login()`) inside a `try`/`except` block, in order to allow methods to be called on that object, for example: `email = user.email()`. Bearing that in mind, how would I use the `User` object returned by the `login()` method in the example given in your answer?

Comment: @MasterRoot24 so your question isn't about `try/except`, it's about using an instance of a class? I'm very confused....